What are the rules and norms for using private student data (such as test scores) in research?
I reckon that it is common in pedagogical research that researchers would want to use data which is generated as part of the teaching process at their university (e.g. exam scores). What are the norms here regarding consent and information of the students?
A concrete scenario could be that the researchers want to see whether students who took a certain subject before do better on another subject now; or a comparison of outcomes between two modules taught using different methods. The core aspect is that the data is gathered independently of the research project, but it is not public.

Just to be clear, you're talking about research per se, not instructors evaluating decisions about their courses? I.e., work that will be submitted for publication.

@AzorAhai-him- Yes, stuff that is meant to be published.

The exempt (and "partly" exempt) categories under IRB rules are detailed at Basic HHS Policy for Protection of Human Research Subjects: §46.104 Exempt research. See part (d), specifically.
This includes quite a lot of pedagogical research, but requires that students not be disadvantaged by any such research. It also requires something like anonymity for the subjects, though it seems like a rather weak form.
Even if you aren't trying to get a specific project approved, it might be worth the effort to have a conversation with someone on the local IRB committee for their advice.
While these are US rules and stronger rules may appear elsewhere, seem logical/ethical. The goal of such proper pedagogical research is to improve education so knowing the effects of various practices is needed.

The short answer is: Talk to your Institutional Review Board (IRB).
